# Get values from HttpPostedFileBase in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

My controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowExcelFile(HttpPostedFileBase getFile)
    {
        //Make something with values of getFile
        return PartialView("ShowExcelFile");
    }
```

In my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowExcelFile", "ShowExcel", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
     <input type="file" id="getFile" name="getFile" /><br />
     <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />
}
```

How can I read the values from getFile?

Comment: Take a look at [Excel Data Reader](https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to parse an Excel file is to use a library such as [Excel Data Reader](https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) (available as a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/) as well). And once installed, reading your Excel file is quite simple.

```
using Excel;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowExcelFile(HttpPostedFileBase getFile)
{
    if (getFile != null && getFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // .xlsx
        IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(getFile.InputStream);

        // .xls
        IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(getFile.InputStream);

        reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true; // if your first row contains column names
    }

    return PartialView("ShowExcelFile");
}
```

From that point it's hard to tell your exact needs without knowing the contents of your Excel file. You can convert the file to a `System.Data.DataSet` which will contain every sheet and data of your Excel file.

```
DataSet dataSet = reader.AsDataSet();
```

Comment: Can't find Excel Data Reader from my NuGet, but I tried to download it manually. Where do I put the .dlls?

Comment: @krillezzz [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/). Or you can look for it within Visual Studio by searching "ExcelDataReader".

Comment: Just a question, Is this also possible to do with Ajax.BeginForm ? Cause I wanna return my partialview inside a div-tag

Comment: Uploading files via Ajax isn't possible, you have to resort to using some sort of trickery involving either iframes or Flash if I remember correctly. That would probably be something worth posting as a new question of it's own as I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: @Dom uploading files via ajax is totally possible.

https://cmatskas.com/upload-files-in-asp-net-mvc-with-javascript-and-c/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ViewModel to do this by adding it as a property:

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowExcelFile", "ShowExcel", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Files, new { type = "file", name = "Files" })<br />
     <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />
}
```

**Model**

```
public class AModel 
{
    public AModel()
    {
        Files = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    }

    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
    // Rest of model details
}
```

You can the retrieve the files by removing the un-needed parameter i.e.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowExcelFile(AModel model) 
 {
    var file = model.Files[0];
    ...
 }
```

Comment: This is working, but how can I access the file values? It's an Excelfile, so how can I read the file?

Comment: if you need to access to the document itself you should get the ado.net adapter and get read the file

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what do you mean by

> Make something with values of getFile

To get extension of file use

```
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(getFile.FileName);

//save this file using



string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content")), "Name"+fileExtension);
file.SaveAs(path);
```